# I need to open a brokerage account in the US from AUSTRALIA

Tags: banking, brokerage

Does anyone know if I may be able to open a brokerage account in the united states but living in  Australia, to use in trading.

Comment: Are you a US resident or an Australian Resident? What is your actual situation? You may need to provide a lot more details if you want an accurate answer. As a lot of brokerage accounts in Australia allow you to trade US and other international shares and other markets.

Comment: I'm an Australian resident

Comment: Is there something you can't trade with an Australian broker?

Comment: I'm just worried about the conversion rate and or Hedge my fund.

Answer (score 1):

[At some places yes, at others, no](http://usatoday30.usatoday.com/money/perfi/columnist/krantz/story/2012-05-14/online-brokerage-requirements-for-foreign-citizens/54964466/1).

As noted in the article, I've heard [more] recently that TD Ameritrade will open accounts for non-US residents, probably excluding [countries where they have separate sites](https://www.tdameritrade.com/international.page), as long as the prospective client has the funds to put in the account.